# Find text in a project but within a specific folder

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

How do I do something like 'Find in Folder' from atom/vscode/sublime in spacemacs?

I have helm and projectile installed.

I have `SPC-/` set to find in the complete project. But not able to figure out a way to find inside a folder/directory within a project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use the Emacs function:

```
M-x find-grep-dired
```

Emacs will ask you the directory and the string (or regexp) you want to search.

This will open a dired **Find** buffer where you can, for instance:

- press the 'm' key to select files
- press the 'Q' key to perform a search/replace over all the selected files

Answer (score 0):

If you have Projectile installed (and chances are that you have if you are using Spacemacs) you can do `projectile-replace` or `projectile-replace-regexp`.

By default it works interactively so you don't have to replace all occurrences if you don't want to.

Projectile works on projects. So either a directory (and its subdirs) with a `.projectile` file in it (just in the parent dir) or if it's a git repo.

I've just used it and it works great.

Here some documentation on it: https://codelearn.me/2017/10/20/projectile-search-replace.html